# Displaying xml in win-1250

Tags: php, xml, encoding

I have an xml file in win 1250.
When I display the file in browser, I have an error:

> unsupported encoding win-1250

My xml declaration looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="win-1250" ?>
```

In the body of the document I have characters of my local language.

How can I display xml file in win-1250? 
I have an access to php so maybe this the way?

Answer (score 1):

`win-1250` isn't a valid IANA charset code, you should use `windows-1250`.